# acts_as_votable - Display number of votes a user has received on a particular model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application, users can post guides and upvote/downvote them. I calculate a score for a guide like this in my Guide model:

```
  def score
    upvotes.count - downvotes.count
  end
```

I want to be able to show the current user his score on all guides he has posted. Something like:

```
<%= current_user.guides.score %>
```

Any idea how to do this? It's very simple. I just can't pinpoint the right variables to use.

Comment: You want the _total_ score for all guides?

Comment: Just the ones that belong to the current user.

Comment: But you don't want to list them individually, you want a single total value?

Comment: Yup. Single total value. A single integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
current_user.guides.map { |guide| [ guide.name, guide.score ] }
```

Here `guide.name` is the name/title of your guide.  This statement above will give you guide name with their scores in an array.

**Update:** To get the sum of guides scores for the `current_user`:

```
current_user.guides.sum(&:score)
```

Comment: How would you display the sum of the score of all the guides the user has posted?

Comment: You should be able to do `current_user.guides.sum(&:score)` wouldn't you?

Comment: @vee Not sure that will work, but `current_user.guides.map(&:score).sum` should.

Comment: @vee - Your commented answer worked. Thanks! Make it an official answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @vee - Any idea how to display a list of users in order of sum score? Say I take `current_user.guides.sum(&:score)` and make it it's own action.

Comment: @DylanRichards, you want to do that on the db side or are you okay with sorting after building the score array? `User.all.map(&:guides).flatten.map(&:score).sort` (`flatten` might not be necessary, check the result of `User.all.map(&:guides)` first) should be array solution.  I would strongly suggest you to ask a different question for this as it's different from this question and keeping questions separate is important.

Answer (score 2):

In controller:

```
@user_total_scores = current_user.guides.map(&:score).inject(0, :+)
```

View:

```
<%= @user_total_scores %>
```

Comment: Don't want to iterate through each of them. Just want the sum of it in one place.